# Serilog Adds Text to Log Message

Tags: serilog

Why and how is Serilog adding the bolded extra text to the output? I have noticed its only on levels 'above' Debug. Information, Warn, Error all have it.

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:g} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "logs\\SyncAgent-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": "7",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithExceptionDetails", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "SyncAgent"
    }
  }
}
```

[02/17/2021 17:25 DBG] Registered ApiClient for type [SyncAgent].

[02/17/2021 17:25 DBG] Initialized...

[02/17/2021 17:25 DBG] LiteDbLocalDataRepository initialized

***info: SyncAgent.SyncAgent[0]
LiteDbLocalDataRepository initialized***
[02/17/2021 17:25 INF] LiteDbLocalDataRepository initialized

***fail: SyncAgent.SyncAgent[0]
LiteDbLocalDataRepository initialized***
[02/17/2021 17:25 ERR] LiteDbLocalDataRepository initialized

***warn: SyncAgent.SyncAgent[0]
LiteDbLocalDataRepository initialized***
[02/17/2021 17:25 WRN] LiteDbLocalDataRepository initialized

Answer (score 0):

When you are configuring services to add serilog, you can clear all log providers.

I am not sure what was causing it still, but I have confirmed this has removed the extra text that was being added.

```
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
           .ReadFrom
           .Configuration(ConsoleAppUtils.BuildConfigurationFromSettingsFile(SettingsFile))
           .CreateLogger();

        Builder.ConfigureServices(x =>
            x.AddLogging(configure =>
            {
                configure.ClearProviders();
                configure.AddSerilog(logger);
            })
        ) ;
```